# Vue-form-wizard: Make the tab index dynamic by the route

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, tabs

I want to navigate in the tabs by the url.

Tab-content prop `route`: I can set an anchor that is shown in the url.

Form-wizard prop `start-index`: I can navigate to the right tab.

How can I make the `start-index` prop dynamically what route which index has?

So I can type in the url www.website.com/#a goes to tabindex 0 and www.website.com/#b goes to tabindex 1

**package:** vue-form-wizard

```
 <form-wizard :start-index="1">
   <tab-content title="a" route="#a">
     <p>a</p>
   </tab-content>

   <tab-content title="b" route="#b">
     <p>b</p>
   </tab-content>
 </form-wizard>
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely setting start-index doesn't seem to work.

But you can use changeTab to set the tab, for example in mounted().

There you can get the url
var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
or
var currentUrl = this.$route.query.page

Then change to the right tab with
this.$refs.wizard.changeTab(0, );